# В файл было записано больше чем весь макс. размер файла?

Tags: python

```py
    @staticmethod
    def pdownload(url: str, out: str):
        """Download file from URL with progress."""
        response = get(url, stream=True)

        current_progress = 0

        total = int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))

        size = _convsize(total, PyLoader.CHUNK)

        with open(out, 'wb') as out_file:
            for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=PyLoader.CHUNK):
                size_written = out_file.write(data)

                current_progress += size_written

                yield {
                    'percentage': _percentage(current_progress, total),
                    'current_progress': current_progress,
                    'size_written': size_written,
                    'size': size,
                    'totalbytes': total,
                    'chunk': PyLoader.CHUNK # 1024
                }
```

```py
file = PyLoader.pdownload('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e', 'sidebar.svg')

for data in file:
    print(data)
```

При запуске этого кода, percentage уже с самого начала больше 100%, а если посмотреть на size_written то он уже больше чем весь размер файла (size_written: 2415 > totalbytes: 2368), как решить проблему? может я как то не так считаю size_written?

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается `response.headers.get` возвращает неправильный `content-length`. Значение`total` заменено на `int(urlopen(url).info()['Content-Length'])` и все заработало.

Comment: Всё правильно он возвращает, просто с учётом сжатия, а в файл вы записываете уже разжатый контент

Comment: urlopen не поддерживает сжатие, поэтому там и content-length соответствует размеру несжатого контента

Comment: А ещё всё, вероятно, сломается, если сервер использует Transfer-Encoding: chunked и вообще не присылает content-length, но это уже совсем другая история

Comment: О, помню лет 25 назад ещё мучился с этим Content-Length, я смотрю с тех пор мало что изменилось ))